# JavaScript: Change iFrame src from Array

Tags: javascript, iframe

Say I have an array of 3 URLs with an iFrame on the page.

How can I run through these 3 URLs every 5 seconds, and then start over?
Ideally the page will stay the same, just the iFrame src will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var u = 0;
    document.getElementById('myiFrame').setAttribute('src',myUrlArray[u]);
    if(u < myUrlArray.length-1){
        ++u;
    }else{
        u = 0;
    }
},5000);
```

Comment: Yes, setInterval would be more appropriate than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="">Your browser does not support iframes</iframe>
```

You simply need to do this in Javascript:

```
var URLs = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
var currURL = 0;

function cycle() {
    currURL = (currURL + 1) % 3;
    document.getElementById("ifr").src = URLs[currURL];
    setTimeout(cycle, 5000);
}

cycle();
```

Comment: use "% URLs.length" instead of "% 3"

Answer (score 0):

The code in the as correct marked answer does not work as it always counts too high. Here is the code which works for me flawlessly:

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="myiFrame" src="a.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

<script>
    var myUrlArray = [
        "a.html", 
        "b.html", 
        "c.html"
    ];
    var u = 1;

    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('myiFrame').setAttribute('src',myUrlArray[u]);
        u++;
        if (u == myUrlArray.length) {u = 0;}
    },1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```