# Repeating a for loop by re-setting variable to 0

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why won't the below make the var i = 0 again and re-run through the loop?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++){ 
    if (i == menuitems.length){
      i = 0;
    };
    $(menuitems[i]).delay(3000*i).queue(function() {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    });   
  };
```

Comment: Because `i == menuitems.length` will never be true in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around this issue using the below code:

```
$('#scroll').click(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
  var u = 0;
  document.getElementById('maps').setAttribute('src',myUrlArray[u]);
  if(u < myUrlArray.length){
      ++u;
  }else{
      u = 0;
  }
},3000);
  });
```

My question ended up being very similar to this one:
[JavaScript: Change iFrame src from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272810/javascript-change-iframe-src-from-array)

Answer (score 2):

Because "i" will **never** be `==` to `menuitems.length` (in the body of the loop; it will be *after* the loop, of course). Your loop terminates as soon as "i" is not less than `menuitems.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when `i` becomes `menuitems.length`, the for loop condition (`i < menuitems.length`) becomes false, so the loop stops.

Try this instead:

```
if (i == menuitems.length - 1){
```

But then, you'll need some way to make the loop stop; otherwise it will just keep going and freeze your browser.

Comment: I tried this and the page just freezes as soon as my click sets the loop off.

Comment: @PaulBentham Because the loop never stops.

Comment: @PaulBentham what would you *expect* to happen if you deliberately cause the loop to start over from the beginning?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping for though, if the user click's scroll then it should be going through the loop endlessly.  My intention was to put a condition in that if they clicked it again (or one of the other menuitems) then it would stop.

Comment: @PaulBentham But the loop is infinite, so it will just keep going, and never stop, and you can't do anything else while an infinite loop is freezing up the browser.

Comment: How would I get around the issue then? I'm trying to set it as if it was a carousel of photo's or something.

Comment: You can't have a loop that is continuously executing with no break, because then there is no way for anything else to be executing, including the ui, that's why it's frozen. If you want to continue executing some block of code, you need to give the browser some breathing time. Use a timer (setTimeout) to execute a function with a certain amount of time in between

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I don't think 'by not doing it' is a great answer... I think a lot of webpages have a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work, because JavaScript code is not interruptible. Events like timer expirations will not be executed while you're inside the loop, so nobody from the outside will set an exit condition for you.

```
for (var i = 0;;i++)
{
    i %= menuitems.length; // loops i when it exceeds list length

    // the expiration of these delays will not interrupt the loop
    $(menuitems[i]).delay(3000*i).queue(function() {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    });

    // if you don't compute a break condition from within the loop, you're toast
    if (some_break_condition) break; 
}
```

Now if you want a scroller, the way to go is something like:

```
var timer;
var period = 1000; // milliseconds
function startScroll ()
{
    stopScroll();
    timer = window.setInterval(
           move_something_around (), // do you scroll here
           period);
}

function stopScroll ()
{
    if (timer)
    {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

// html

<button type="button" onclick="startScroll()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopScroll()" >Stop </button>
```